# PHP MYSQL array foreach and insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

**tbl1**

```
id | detail
1  | this, that
2  | these, those
```

**tbl2**

```
id | visit  | cost
1  | this   | 20
2  | that   | 30
3  | these  | 40
4  | those  | 50
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 

$id=$_GET['id'];    
$detail=$_GET['detail'];
$pieces = explode(",", $rows['detail']);

    // $pieces[0]; piece1
    // $pieces[1]; piece2        
    // $pieces[2]; piece2        
    // $pieces[3]; piece3    
    // $pieces[4]; piece4

    foreach($pieces[1] as $test){            

$query="SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE
  $test = tbl2.cost AND
  tbl1.id='$id'";
    }   

$result=mysql_query($query) or die("error: " . mysql_error());

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
?>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><input value="<? echo $rows['code'];?>" readonly="readonly"/></td>
    <td><input value="<? echo $rows['cost']; ?>" readonly="readonly"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<?php
}
?>
```

for id=1, array 0=>this, 1=>that
So, `foreach($pieces[1] as $test)`, it means "that"

The above works, but, when I change `$pieces[1]` to `$pieces[0]`, I still get the result which corresponds with `$pieces[1]`.  And, when I change it to `$pieces[4]` which doesn't exist, I again get the result which corresponds with `$pieces[1]`.

Where am I doing wrong? How can I make this array work?

According to tbl1.id=1 piece[0]=>this, piece[1]=>that and I want to make it work for my tables. Please help.

Comment: You have `$pieces = explode(",", $rows['detail']);` before you've done  the database query that assigns to `$rows`. Should that be `$pieces = explode(",", $detail);`?

Answer (score 1):

$pieces[1], the variable you are using in your foreach loop is a string, not an array. You should be looping through the $pieces array so:

```
foreach($pieces as $test){
```

... NOT

```
foreach($pieces[1] as $test){
```

Comment: error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= tbl2.cost AND tbl1.id='some numbers'' at line 3

Comment: echo $query; what does that return?

Comment: return is : SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE = tbl2.cost AND tbl1.id='some numbers'

$pieces[1] is missing

Comment: where is $rows['detail'] populated?

Comment: try to echo only $pieces[1] only, also why are you comparing tbl2.cost(integer) with $pieces[1](string).

Comment: echo only $pieces[1] is empty. actually it should be according to tbl1.id=1, 'this'

Comment: If you want to compare with 'this', the query should contain something like `WHERE tbl2.visit = '$test'`

Answer (score 1):

$pieces[1] is not an array but an element of an array($pieces),
so better use without loop statement,

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE
  $pieces[1] = tbl2.cost AND
  tbl1.id='$id'";
```

Thanks

Comment: error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= tbl2.cost AND tbl1.id='some numbers'' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
$result=mysql_query($query) or die("error: " . mysql_error());
```

It will return a result of the from query. But what is your query? It is the last string you set $query to, which is the last time iteration of your for loop. That seems to be inefficient and not your intended behavior.

Assuming that you want all the results (and don't care about query optimization), you could do something like this:

```
foreach($pieces as $test){            
    $query="SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE
    $test = tbl2.cost AND tbl1.id='$id'";

    $result[]=mysql_query($query) or die("error: " . mysql_error());
}

foreach ($results as $result){
    $rows=array_push(mysql_fetch_array($result));
}
```

Now, if you only want details from a specific piece, you don't even need a for loop.

```
// replace 3 with the desired element
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl1, tbl2 WHERE
$pieces[3] = tbl2.cost AND tbl1.id='$id'";

$result=mysql_query($query) or die("error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Can you do a print_r on $pieces[3]?

Comment: empty result. I dont understand why?